# finding a parametric equation of a curve formed by deforming an ellipse

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, parametric, parametrization

I have a deformed curve from ellipse with the following form:
$$\left( \frac{x}{a} \right)^2+\left( \frac{y}{b} \right)^2-\alpha\left(\frac{x}{a}\frac{y}{b}\right)^2=1,$$ where for $\alpha=0$ we get an ellipse, I know for ellipse the parametric equation has the following form $$x=a\ cos(\theta)\ ;\ y=b\ sin(\theta)$$ where $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$, I am wondering how to include the effect of the coupled  term $\alpha\left(\frac{x}{a}\frac{y}{b}\right)^2$. [image: Green is the deformed curve]

Comment: It's a quartic (a degree 4 curve) for $\alpha\neq 0.$ E.g. for $\alpha=1$ it's the four lines $-((x-a)(x+a)(y-b)(y+b))/(a^2b^2)=0.$

Comment: Quartics are much more complicated than conics. In general they have [28](http://sites.math.washington.edu/~vinzant/research/quartics.html) bitangents.

Comment: Thank you, In fact, I am intersted in $- 0.5<\alpha <0$, which gives shapes closer to ellipses.@Jan-MagnusØkland

Comment: The quartic for $a=2,b=1,\alpha=-\frac14$ has genus 3 and there's is no rational parameterization. See [the wikipedia article on plane quartic curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_plane_curve).